# Overriding Component Create Constructor in Separate Design-Time package

Tags: delphi, components

Programming Environment: Delphi 6 and upwards

I am aware of the fact that since Delphi 6, custom components must have separate design- and run-time package. All run time features of the a component must therefore be in a separate unit and packaged separately to the component's design-time package.

My problem is the following: My component has code that needs to be run both when it is created on the form at run time and, additional code that needs to be run at design-time, when the component is placed on the form. I have managed to put the run time code into the separate run time unit, package it and deploy it successfully.

However, in the separate design-time module unit, how do I reference and add the design-time code that needs to be included into the component's create constructor during design-time, when the component gets placed onto the form?

Comment: They don't have to be in separate units nor packages, you can always check `if csDesigning in ComponentState then YouAreAtDesignTime`.

Comment: TLama is correct. The problem with design time code is just that some of the ToolsAPI units can't be linked to run time packages without violating the license agreement (so you shouldn't do it, obviously). As long as you don't use those units, it is perfectly possible to include your own design time code in your own units.

Comment: Could you be more specific about whát you want to do in the constructor? And why it needs to be in the constructor?

Comment: If the entire VCL can be built without improperly using designtime features in their components incorrectly, yours can as well. There's absolutely no reason to mix DesignIDE/DesignIntf features into your runtime code; it should always be possible to separate them properly.

Comment: Thank you NGLN. When the component is dropped onto the form at design-time, I write to a database details regarding the parent form. To access this information, requires DesignIDE routines which cannot be included in the runtime interface because when a package is compiled, DesignIDE.dcu' not found occurs. Therefore, a separate design-time constructor is required. Thank you

Comment: Thanks Ken White. I agree that one should be able to separate runtime and design time but my question is: How do you have a separate 'constructor create' for the design-time package?

Comment: Override `SetParent`, check `ComponentState`, retrieve parent form, ét voila. What properties of the form do you need that are not accessible from the run time package? Please be specific.

Comment: When I drop the component onto the form in design-time, I need to store the name of the project it is dropped onto into a database. The only way I see that one can get the name of the project at design-time is using GetActiveProject.FileName found in ToolsAPI. Additionally, I'm migrating a component suite (DesignerForms-Guild) from Delphi5 to Delphi2005. That component uses many calls that are in DesignIDE but is not currently in separate runtime and design-time packages. So, when these components are placed in a application, on compile, the DesignIDE.dcu not found error occurs.

Comment: @user1202134, do you *need* or do you *want* to put the name of the project in a database. If it's a *want*, maybe you can work around the problem, keep the design clean and figure out an other way of populating the database. In all honesty it looks like a clever trick that looks good but it's not worth it. You're introducing points of failure. Just for fun, imagine your database gets corrupted and you can't open your IDE to do some other kinds of work, because through this clever trick you introduced a dependency on the said database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use callbacks?

From your designtime package initialization code do this:

```
unit MyDsgnUnit;

interface

  //TMyHook defined in AnImplUnit

  TMyDesignHandlerObject = class
      procedure MyMethod(Sender:TObject;ParentForm:TObject); { must match TMyHook }
  end;

implementation

uses AnImplUnit, DesignUnitNamesHere;

procedure TMyDesignHandlerObject.MyMethod(Sender:TObject);
var
  newObject:TMyComponent;
begin
   newObject := TMyComponent(Sender);
   DoSomethingThatneedsDesigntimeStuff(newObject);
end;

finalization
   ADesignHandlerObject.Free;
initialization
   ADesignHandlerObject := TMyDesignHandlerObject.Create;
   AnImplUnit.AfterConstructionHook := TDesignHandlerObject.MyMethod;
```

and in your component do something like this:

```
unit AnImplUnit;
interface

type
   TMyHook = procedure(Sender:TObject;ParentForm:TObject) of object;
var

  AfterConstructionHook:TMyHook;

implementation

...

procedure TMyComponent.Create(AOwner:TComponent);
begin
   inherited Create(AOwner);
   DOMyStuff;
   if Assigned(AfterConstructionHook)
       AfterConstructionHook(Sender,Parent);
end;
```

**Update** Flushed out example more.  There is no reason you can't add more parameters to the AfterConstructionHook, but since your reference to Sender is already of type TMyComponent, I don't see the point, when you can access everything public or protected, in `TMyComponent(Sender)` from within your hook function, and if you inherit locally (known as a protected-access class), you can access the protected stuff too.

Comment: Hi Warren P, thank you for your kind input. This seems like a viable solution. As I'm not too familiar with this concept, could you kindly elaborate a little more, perhaps giving me a simple, but complete example? Thank you.

Comment: The example above is nearly complete. I will add a bit more.

Comment: Thank you so much Warren P. Just another question, is it possible to have an additional parameter in the 'AfterConstructionHook' to be sent to the callback?

Comment: Sure why not. But also, "Why?" What do you want to do?

Comment: Thanks for your kind input Warren P. I'm slowly getting there. When the component is dropped onto a form (Create Constructor fired), it checks whether a parent component, which it requires, exists or not. If it does not exist, then it must create it at that point. To create it, I'm using the IDesigner.CreateComponent method. But, this method has parameters i.e. the component class and it's parent component. So, these need to be passed with the AfterConstructionHook. How would one therefore include parameters with the callback? Thank you

Comment: Why aren't you doing ALL of that from the Designtime callback function? Not sure why you can't just get the parent from `TMyComponent(Sender).Parent` for instance.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if you find this one answers your question. Or another answer, if it answers it better. But please choose one.

Answer (score 4):

You can separate design time behaviour from run time behaviour with

```
if [not] (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
```

But if your constructor code needs the `DesignIDE` design time package, e.g. from the units `DesignEditors`, `DesignIntf`, etc..., then I think you are stuck. Maybe some IOTA involvement can help. But since there does not seem to exist a notifier interface for the creation of components, that would require a custom `IOTAFormEditor`. Not that easy, if not impossible.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that yes, the code that is required in the Design-time constructor does use DesignIDE features, hence the need to separate. What do you mean by 'Maybe some IOTA involvement can help'?

Comment: Short answer: Don't. There are always ways around any problem you try to solve by using DesignIDE features in your component constructor.

Comment: @user1202134, why would your constructor need DesignIDE features? There's absolutely no need for anything to do that, and if you are, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks Ken. When I drop my component onto the form at design-time, I need to store also need to store the name of the project into a database. The only way I see that one can get the name of the project at design-time is using GetActiveProject.FileName found in ToolsAPI. Additionally, I'm migrating a component suite (DesignerForms-Guild) from Delphi5 to Delphi2005. That component uses many calls that are in DesignIDE but is not currently in separate runtime and design-time packages. So, when these components are placed in a application, on compile, the DesignIDE.dcu not found error occurs.

Comment: You should probably ask a new question regarding DesignerForms-Guild specifically. If that is a 3rd party component suite that used design time features in a way not intended by the Delphi team at Borland/CodeGear/Embarcadero, there is a risk it simply can't be easily ported to later Delphi versions, but has to be redesigned and reimplemented from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `DPK` defines a symbol of your choice, for example `DESIGNTIME`. Then you'll be able to use something like this to only include design-time units when needed:

```
uses Windows, Whatever, Something
  {$IFDEF DESIGNTIME}
  ,DesignIntf
  {$ENDIF}
  ;
```

Then to the same in your constructor code:

```
constructor TMyClass.Create(aOwner:TComponent);override;
begin
  inherited;
  {$IFDEF DESIGNTIME}
  // I'm at design time.
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

When using this technique you should either use a separate `DCU` directory for your pacakge and your normal executable, or do a `build` each time you switch from the design time package to other projects. That's because Delphi will only re-build a `DCU` if the `PAS` has changed, when in this case the `PAS` doesn't tell the whole story, defined symbols also matter. If you have a `DCU` on disk that was compiled by Delphi while you were building your design time project, you might see a `ToolsApi.DCU not found` when trying to compile a normal project. Rebuilding re-compiles the DCU and makes the message go away. Just as well, if you re-compile (not re-build) the design time project after you built a normal project, your DCU might be stuck in it's non-DESIGNTIME state, leaving you without your special design-time behavior.

Comment: Hi Cosmin, thank you very much for your input. I will look into doing what you have said. I just want some clarification. Would I still have to devide the runtime and design-time into separate units and packages to be compiled separately? Thank you.

Comment: It's entirely up to you and there's no limit to the amount (or kind) of code that can be conditionally compiled in (or out). Just don't over do it, because you'll end up with something difficult to read and maintain.

Comment: Conditional defines would become a bad way to do this, if you also wanted to have a pure Designtime package using a proper Runtime package, and the Runtime package would be loaded not only by the IDE, but also by your own applications, if you build any applications that use runtime BPL packages instead of statically linking.

Comment: Without conditional defines you need to set up a hook that will always be there and be checked, even at runtime when it's no longer needed. I personally don't use runtime packages so I'd prefer this compromise. None the less it's something that need to be taken into account, so +1 to the comment.

Comment: That's why my answer mentions using a callback (or hook).

Answer (score 0):

As long as your code does not require the IDE tools, like design interface and so on, then all you need to do is check the component flag and you can use it anywhere within the component, as follows...

```
procedure TNewEdit.Loaded;
begin
  inherited;
  if (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
    ShowMessage('Designing')
  else
    ShowMessage('Running');
end;
```

However without really knowing what you are attempting to do, there are several doors left open... for example, if you want to change a property value at design time, and a different value at run time, then there are streaming issues you have to deal with.